# Common event for the list of button in window forms?

Tags: winforms

In window forms, can we implement common click event for the button in  "FlowLayoutPanel", can you help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to specify and expand your question. That said all control elements in winforms can have events added to them, same goes for a button in FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: actaully i have one flowlayout panel in that i have dynamic lable and dynamic buttons, now i want button clik events hould be common is it possible?

Comment: Yes, that's possible.  Programmers often overlook the *sender* argument in the Click event handler.  Cast it to Button and you'll know which button was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have a common handler for an event.  As you are creating the `Button` controls:

```
for (Int32 i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Name = "button" + i;
    // OR:  b.Tag = i;
    b.Click += button_Click;
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);  //or whatever you add them to...
}
```

Now that you have specified the same handler for each `Button`:

```
private void button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    switch (b.Name)  // OR: switch (b.Tag) and react to integers instead of strings
    {
        case "button0":
            break;
        case "button1":
            break;
        case "button2":
            break;
    }
}
```

In short, you simply need a way to identify each button and then react to that identifier when the common handler is called.